# awk print matching line and line before the matched

Tags: regex, awk

Following is what I am trying to do using awk. Get the line that matches the regex and the line immediately before the matched and print. I can get the line that matched the regex but not the line immediately before that:

```
awk '{if ($0!~/^CGCGGCTGCTGG/) print $0}'
```

Comment: Lets suppose lines 3 and 4 match the regex.  do you want 2,3,4 to show up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In this case you could easily solve it with grep:

```
grep -B1 foo file
```

However, if you need to to use awk:

```
awk '/foo/{if (a && a !~ /foo/) print a; print} {a=$0}' file
```

Comment: How about awk '{if ($0~/>/) head=$0;getline} {if ($0~/^CGCGGCTGCTGG/) print head"\n"$0}'..is this correct??

Comment: @Sudeep: You can tell yourself whether it's correct by testing it... but it's longer and harder to understand than marco's suggestion, so why bother?

Comment: Thanks Jeromi, yes, I can test...I am, but getline was bit confusing, this is why I posted to see is someone sees the command and can raise the flag :)

Comment: @Sudeep: My point exactly. It's confusing, so if there's a perfectly good way without it, don't bother confusing yourself.

Comment: Not all grep(1)'s have the "-B" option. It's non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

```
/abc/{if(a!="")print a;print;a="";next}
{a=$0}
```

Comment: your script will not properly handle a case like "bcd\nabc\nabcdef"

Comment: Corrected to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

**use more straightforward pattern search**

`gawk '{if (/^abc$/) {print x; print $0};x=$0}' file1 > file2`

Answer (score 1):

I created the following awk script. Prints the matching line as well as the previous 2 lines. You can make it more flexible from this idea.

**search.awk**

```
{
    a[0]=$0;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
       getline;
       if(i==0){
            a[1]=$0;
       }
       if(i==1){
            if($0 ~ /message received/){
                print a[0];     
                print a[1];
                print $0;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
awk '{print $0}' LogFile.log | awk -f search.awk
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `grep -EB1 '^CGCGGCTGCTGG'`

The `awk` to do the same thing is very long-winded, see Marco's answer.

Comment: Thanks Marco and Solmojo..grep works too, just waned to do in awk.

Comment: As a learning exercise, it's a good thing to do, however, the grep will also run faster, and on biometrics that's probably a useful feature.

Comment: If you only have to do that, sure. But if you need to do that as part of a longer awk script, then you need a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly off-topic, but I used the answer from belisarius to create my own variation of the above solution, that searches for the **Nth** entry, and returns that and the previous line.

```
awk -v count=1 '/abc/{{i++};if(i==count){print a;print;exit}};{a=$0}' file
```