# Is there any alternative for “grep -B 1 “ as I can’t use grep with -B to get the o/p

Tags: shell, unix, grep

My grep on MacOS does not support GNU grep's `-B count` option. I need an alternative for below command:

```
while read x; do
    find . -name \*$x\* -exec cat {} + |
    grep -i -B 1 "failed with status"
done < x
```

Below is the command output which I need:

```
/phobos/user/jwang223/cdjic_mailservice restoring...
Backup failed with status 70.
```

Comment: Error :grep: illegal option -- B
Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file . . .

Comment: Please [edit] to move info from your comments into the question.

Comment: done .... -B1 and -B 1 both was tried bit same error

Comment: "done"? It looks more like you removed information in contrast to adding some. The edit comment is not visible in the question you know.... I undid that accident for you.

Comment: Please [edit] to move info from your first two comments into the question.

Comment: You commented on an answer "-B option not working with while loop." That seems to be the answer to your question to me..... The while loop which only feeds one line into each grep prevents grep from doing anything meaningful with the `-B1` option. That makes the "What is wrong?" question unclear to me. Please explain. Or [edit] to phrase the question "How can I achieve .... ?" which is answered in the answer below. (But not into a different question which the answer does NOT answer, because that would be an unfair "moving target" question.)

Comment: @Yunnosch  -B option is not available on my machine can you suggest any alternate

Comment: What makes you think that `-B` is not available? Please [edit] additional information into your question. E.g. which grep you use, what `grep --help` in your environment yields concerning that option....

Comment: I tried man grep

Comment: It would seem on your Mac OS there is no GNU grep, but a different grep. What about installing or compiling GNU grep? See https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/

Comment: @Jens This won’t be possible as I m running this on server host where I don’t have root access.

Comment: You usually don't need to be root to compile a program. You can install GNU grep in `$HOME/bin/grep` and adjust your PATH.

Comment: Are you on macos? I see [macos grep](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html), and the output looks similar to [hp-ux grep](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/grep.1.html).

Comment: You are mentioning that you run this on a server, what is the OS of the server?

Comment: Solaris 11.4 server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to simplify the loop into a single `awk` (standadr Linux awk/gawk) command like this:

```
while read x; do
    awk 'BEGINFILE{l = ""} /failed with status/{print FILENAME": "l RS $0}{l = $0}' $(find -name "*$x*")
done < x
```

Notice the matching regex pattern is case sensitive. Change it to your case insestivie like this:
`/failed with status/` --> `/[fF][aA][iI][lL][eE][dD] [wW][iI][tT][hH] [sS][tT][aA][tT][uU][sS]/`.

```
while read x; do
    awk 'BEGINFILE{l = ""} /[fF][aA][iI][lL][eE][dD] [wW][iI][tT][hH] [sS][tT][aA][tT][uU][sS]/{print FILENAME": "l RS $0}{l = $0}' $(find -name "*$x*")
done < x
```

#### `awk` script Explanation

```
BEGINFILE {previusLine = ""} # On file reading start, reset variable previusLine
/failed with status/         # On lines mathching regex pattern "failed with status"
{
                             # print filename prefix + previousLine + newline + current line
  print FILENAME ": " previusLine RS $0;
} 
{                            # On each line
  previusLine = $0;          # save the current line into variable previusLine
}
```

Comment: This is not standard AWK, but a simple GNU awk, it contains extensions. Since the OP indicates that he cannot make use of GNU grep, it seems doubtful that he can use GNU awk.

Comment: This also does not give the same intended result. This resets everything at every file, while the OP just wants to see the output of the cat of all files combined.

Comment: Both comments are correct. `gawk` is standard in Linux machines. And the test is reset on each file. The user can remove the section `BEGIN{l =""}` and it behaves like `cat` of a single file.

Answer (score 1):

-B for grep is working fine in while loop as well. Please re-check formatting in your once.

```
 cat boo
a test line
failed with status
some random text


find . -name *b* -exec cat {} \; | grep -B 1 'failed with status'
a test line
failed with status

cat x
boo

while read x; do find . -name \*$x\* -exec cat {} + | grep -i -B 1 "failed with status" ;done < x
a test line
failed with status
```

Comment: @Misrtyvib I have edited my answer . I suspect there must be some non-whitespace characters 'B' and grep . how about manually typing the whole grep command.

Comment: Maybe his grep does not support -B? It would be good to know the operating system.

Comment: OS - macOS Mojave

Comment: @Jens -B option not preset under man grep ....this is total disaster for me ...any alternative?

Comment: @Misrtyvib check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891383/awk-print-matching-line-and-line-before-the-matched)

Comment: @Jens I tried : while read x; do find . -name \*$x\* -exec cat {} \; | awk '/failed with status/{if (a && a !~ /failed with status/) print a; print} {a=$0}' ;done < x
 but its way to slow and complicated with o/p

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk`.

```
find . -name "*$x*" -exec cat {} + |
awk 'length(prev) != 0 && tolower($0) ~ /failed with status/{ print prev; print } { prev=$0 }'
```

I guess also `sed`:

```
sed -n '1{h;b;}; H; y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/; /failed with status/{ x; p; s/.*//; n; h; b; }; x; s/[^\n]*\n//; x'
```

Comment: Sed is not working only AWk works that will be fine I guess

Comment: how to add previous 5 line

Answer (score 0):

In the comment you mention two important clues to the problem:

1. You seem to run the command on a server (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113106/is-there-any-alternative-for-grep-b-1-as-i-can-t-use-grep-with-b-to-get-the#comment113376094_64113106))

   > *This won’t be possible as I m running this on server host where I don’t have root access.*
2. And you mention the following error (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113106/is-there-any-alternative-for-grep-b-1-as-i-can-t-use-grep-with-b-to-get-the#comment113373922_64113106)):

   > `grep: illegal option -- B Usage: grep [-c|-l|-q] -bhinsvw pattern file`

This makes me believe, that you are running the command **not** on OSX but on HP-UNIX. Checking out the [man page](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/grep.1.html) shows that this version does not support the GNU grep extensions.

you can mimic the `-i -B count` option using awk:

```
awk -v c=count -v s="failed with status" '
        BEGIN{c=c+1}{a[FNR%c]=$0}
        (tolower($0) ~ s){
           for(i=(FNR>c)*(FNR-c)+1;i<=FNR;++i) print a[i%c]; print "--"
        }'
```

if `count==1` you can just do:

```
awk '(tolower($0)~/failed with status/){print (FNR>1?p ORS:"") $0}{p=$0}'
```

Comment: @Misrtyvib I've updated the script. If it does not work, there will be something wrong in your script.